# Adding custom structure to replace ancient_city_center

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I would like to have a custom structure I made replace the `city_center` structure of an ancient city, except when I do that, cities do not generate at all.

To make sure it was working, I replaced the `tall_ruins` structures instead, and then cities did generate again, but then those ruins did not generate.

What am I doing wrong? How do I replace one part of a city?

Comment: The tagging issue in the history is [being discussed on Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16477/185203) (which I realize I should have done in the first instance rather than getting into another edit war)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: So apparently it was due to my structure not having a jigsaw setting the city center. At that point my structure generated, but not the rest of the city. The solution? More jigsaws.